# What's the difference between apache "options" directive code that append values with "+" sign & the values without "+" sign? Example code is in body

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp, virtual-host

what the difference between this code=>

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\coderevenge.com">
    
    options  Indexes FollowSymlinks Includes ExeCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    
    
    </Directory>
```

And this code here =>

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\coderevenge.com">

options  +Indexes +FollowSymlinks +Includes +ExeCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted


</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch03_11.htm :

---

The arguments can be preceded by "+" or "-", in which case they are added or removed. The following command, for example, adds `Indexes` but removes `ExecCGI`:

```
Options +Indexes -ExecCGI
```

If no options are set, and there is no  directive, the effect is as if All had been set, which means, of course, that MultiViews is not set. If any options are set, All is turned off. This has at least one odd effect: if you have an ... /htdocs directory without an index.html and a very simple Config file, and you access the site, you see a directory of ... /htdocs. For example:

```
User Webuser 
Group Webgroup 
ServerName www.butterthlies.com 
DocumentRoot /usr/www/site.ownindex/htdocs
```

If you add the line:

```
Options ExecCGI
```

and access it again, you see the following rather baffling message:

```
FORBIDDEN 
You don't have permission to access / on this server
```

The reason is that when Options is not mentioned, it is, by default, set to All. By switching ExecCGI on, you switch all the others off, including Indexes. The cure for the problem is to edit the Config file so that the new line reads:

```
Options +ExecCGI
```

Similarly, if "+" or "-" are not used and multiple options could apply to a directory, the last most specific one is taken. For example:

```
Options ExecCGI 
Options Indexes
```

results in only Indexes being set, which might surprise you.

Comment: As an Example, What's the best configuration to host website from home; can you give me off the code that works well for hosting website from home keeping security in view?

Comment: @CodeStar that would fill an entire book and is way outside of your initial question. There are massive amounts of tutorials and documentation regarding webserver setup, NAT configuration, DDNS and server hardening.

Comment: Note that you **should not** use XAMPP to deploy a publicly accessible website. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/how-safe-is-it-to-install-xampp-on-my-home-computer-to-test-php-code

Comment: yeah It's outside of my initial question. I'm asking the code because; that might help me compare code and understand better and I'm currently working on making a youtube tutorial that will show how to host website from home. And It's getting difficult to find the right documentation that makes me understand about this permissions thing.

Comment: @CodeStar “I'm currently working on making a youtube tutorial that will show how to host website from home.” You literally do not know what you are doing but you are using the answers provided here so you can create a YouTube video that will advise people on how to do this? Why? If you don’t understand something, I would not want to follow _any_ advice in your video. Especially when you are relying on others on this site to do the heavy lifting for you.